# unable to retrieve columns value from table using jdbc query

Tags: jdbc

The below given is the whole code . Its only printing "Connected successfully". But it is not executing the query part. Guide me where i am going wrong. Anything after Resultset is not executed or printed. The string query sql3 contains baseParam and denom. This two fields contains the column name from which i want to retrieve the values. I am unable to do it. Guide me as i am going wrong somewhere. I even  tried the same resulset loop using the rs object but none is executed after Resultset in the code. I am not able to convert it in java format the mysql query

```
package com.journaldev.json;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.*;

import static java.lang.Math.*;

import java.io.*;

import com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData;

public class Efficiency {

     static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
     static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
     static final String DB_USER = "root";
     static final String DB_PASSWORD = "root";
     static final String dbName = "raas";



        public static void main(String[] args)   {

            try{
                effFunc();
            }


            catch (Exception q){
                q.getMessage();
            }


        }
        static void effFunc() throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException{

                Connection conn = null;


                // STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
                Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

                // STEP 3: Open a connection
                System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION + dbName, DB_USER,
                        DB_PASSWORD);
                System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
                String baseParam;
                //String[] subParam ;
                baseParam= "Job_Render";

                String sql3="";
                String denom="";
                String sql1="";
                final String[] COL={ "LC_Final","LC_Preview"};
                denom = "(" + COL[0] + "+" + COL[1] + ")";
                Statement stmt = null;
                //sql1 = "select * from raas.jobs";
                stmt = conn.createStatement();

    //          sql3 =  "select  avg(eff),min(eff),max(eff) from(select ("+baseParam.trim()+"/"+denom.trim()+"))as eff from ras)as s";
                sql3 =  "select 'Efficiency' Field,avg(eff),min(eff),max(eff) from(select (Job_Render/(LC_Final+LC_Preview))as eff from ras)as s";

                System.out.println(sql3);
    //          try{
    //          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql3);
    //          }
    //          catch(Exception p){
    //              p.getStackTrace();
    //              
    //          }System.out.println("Hello");
    //          //System.out.println(rs);
                try{
                ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
                System.out.println(res);


        while(res.next()){

            String JobID = res.getString("JobID");
            System.out.println("Job ID : " + JobID);

            System.out.println("Hello"+sql1);
        }}
                     catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }



    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see a problem but not sure how it would directly contribute to your issue.  In your while() statement you call next() on the ResultSet object res.  But within the loop you call getString() on the rs ResultSet object.  Not sure what you want to have happen but that getString call will not return any results and the cursor for the rs object has not moved to the first row of the result set yet.  You moved it to the first row of res and then tried to get data from rs.  May not fix your but it's not going to generate any useful output.

My guess here is that your res result set is empty so your first time through the while loop, res.next() evaluates to FALSE and you bail out of the loop before you code path ever enters it to execute your println statements.

If ResulSet had a method call getRowCount() you could call that for each ResultSet before you while loop and print the output.  But it doesn't :(

For debugging purposes to test my theory about res being empty do this right before your while loop.

```
System.out.println("res has results: " + res.next());
```

If that is false the first time you hit res.next() your result set is empty and you will never execute the code in the while loop.

Comment: i was testing for both resultset res and rs but it doesn't work for any. I doesn't enter the loop to execute the query

Comment: If your code hits the while statement but does not enter the body then ResultSet.next() is false meaning your queries did not return any rows.

Comment: does your code completes without fetching any results or is there some kind of exception? If there is an exception please show it...